# Module or extension to use for tracking agreements?

Tags: drupal, civicase

I'm looking for a module or extension that has been written for tracking contracts/agreements between organizations within CiviCRM (on drupal). We would like to be able to track all the activities that happen related to that agreement within CiviCRM.

I thought Cases might be a good way to do this, but they are started based on a single contact.

Comment: Is this something along the lines of Organization X has a contract with Organization Y (and neither are your organization)?

Comment: One of the organizations is always my organization, but sometimes it is a multi-organization agreement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can setup CiviCase to enable multiple clients per case, by editing your xml/configuration/Settings.xml file. Set `<AllowMultipleCaseClients>1</AllowMultipleCaseClients>`

Comment: I never knew that Coleman!  Very cool.

Comment: Yea, what would be even cooler is if someone was inspired to submit a PR to expose this setting to the UI so it's not buried in an xml file.

Comment: What are you trying to say? :)

Comment: Oh, nothing... But if you *are* feeling inspired I'd be happy to review your PR ;)

Comment: Hopefully you'll be reviewing a different PR from me pretty soon.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps CiviMember? We have a client that is the purchasing consortium for Higher Education institutions in Southern Africa. They are a non profit membership body and help their members collaborate on procurement contracts. A few years I built them a D6 + Civi system to manage member and supplier info, and tweaked CiviMember, with custom fields and Views to manage their Contracts. It captures supplier and supplier contact info, contract descriptions start/expiry dates, documents etc.