# How can I add additional clients to a case?

Tags: civicase

I want to be able to add additional clients to some cases. The ability to do this used to be configurable via the case settings XML file before the configuration got moved into the UI. What's the current approach (version 4.6.x)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a comment by Coleman on June 18, 2015 regarding a question at [civicrm.stackexchange.com/.../module-or-extension-to-use-for-tracking-agreements](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3364/module-or-extension-to-use-for-tracking-agreements)

```
> You can setup CiviCase to enable multiple clients per case, by editing
> your xml/configuration/Settings.xml file. Set
> <AllowMultipleCaseClients>1</AllowMultipleCaseClients>
```

Comment: Many thanks @OregonJohn - this works, in 4.6 at least. I've not tried it in 4.7 so can't comment on that. Also I've edited the wiki page for 4.6 to reintroduce the relevant section of the Case config notes from 4.4, as otherwise the wiki just says that it all happens via the UI now - which while it might be the aspiration is not the reality.